# What are the Islamic ways to avoid the 'Dirty Habit'?

Tags: halal-haram

I am very shameful to ask such a question, but really can't help self. My problem is that I masturbate and I don't want to do it anymore. I know it is prohibited in Islam and I don't want to be a sinner. Let me tell you how I developed this habit. During holidays I used to read magazines and then I came across a article that spoke that Masturbation reduces stress and is good for health. At that time, I was not even knowing what the word actually mean so I browsed over and now it has become a habit which I want to get out from. Please help. I feel like I have lost my virginity. 
  I know everybody here will suggest me be regular at your prayers and ask for Allah's forgiveness and so on. 
 Yes, I miss out my prayers but that doesn't mean I just don't pray.
   And also do tell me that by doing this kind of none sense have I lost my purity and become a sinner.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing yourself from porn and praying is one thing, the most important and useful is to get married ASAP. 
It will fulfill your desires halal way and makes you understand imaginations and reality.

As Hadith about marriage points to.

> Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings
>   be upon him, said, “Whoever Allah provides with a righteous wife, then
>   Allah has assisted him in half of his religion. Let him fear Allah
>   regarding the second half

Please note that what is meant to be said here is not that marriage is literely half of deen.

What this hadith means is that marriage helps a Muslim to be a rightful Muslim, because marriage helps the Muslim to be emotionally stable, and satisfies his/her human needs without committing sins.